# Add timestamp discord.js presence

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, discord, discord.js

I'm writing a discord bot using discord.js and typescript, and I'm trying to embed a timestamp into the presence. I have a function that would set the presence:

```js
function setPres(text: string, since?: number): void {
    client.user.setPresence({
        status: "online",
        activities: [{name: text}]
    });
}
```

But nowhere in the docs is a way to add a timestamp.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: is [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date) what your looking for?

Comment: You cant set a timestamp inside the presence. Presence is just a string, that is displayed right under a username. You can however use [Discord Timestamps](https://discord.com/developers/docs/reference#message-formatting-timestamp-styles) in the *About me* section of your bot.